# Testing WSO2 ELB

Tags: wso2, load-balancing, wso2-esb

How to check if WSO2 ELB is working properly?
I have a ELB and 2 ELB(1 manager and 1 worker) running, I want to check if ELB is doing its work or not.
I want to check it using a SOAP request, SOAP endpoint should point to ELB or ESB?
I have configured ELB according to what is there in WSO2's documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The WSO2 Elastic Load Balancer has been discontinued. You can download NGinx Plus [1] - the load balancer by NGinx - for which we provide support.

If you are currently using WSO2 ELB and need guidance, please visit our documentation page, Spacially Auto-Scaling in Load Balancer

In order to set up the WSO2 Elastic Load Balancer with one manager and one worker please refer document [1]

In order to check if WSO2 ELB is working properly, you can check it with autoscaling facilities in WSO2 ELB.

Please refer to document [2] for more information on autoscaling.

If you need to send a request to the ESB first you need to point it to ELB.

[1] https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/
[2] http://blog.afkham.org/2011/09/how-to-setup-wso2-elastic-load-balancer.html

Comment: Include more content in your answer as the links might go away